# Using with_fileglob for multiple src and destination while copying

Tags: ansible, yaml

I need it to deploy multiple config files to a series of directories.

```
- name: Deploy apache configuration files
  template: src={{ item.src }} dest=/etc/httpd/{{ item.dest }} mode=0644
  with_fileglob:
  - { src: "../templates/apache_templates/conf/*.conf", dest: 'conf' }
  - { src: "../templates/apache_templates/conf.d/*.conf", dest: 'conf.d' }
```

When I run the above task, I get the error below.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 90, in run
items = self._get_loop_items()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 205, in _get_loop_items
items = mylookup.run(terms=loop_terms, variables=self._job_vars, wantlist=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/lookup/fileglob.py", line 34, in run
term_file = os.path.basename(term)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 121, in basename
i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'rfind'

 fatal: [server1.example.com]: FAILED! => {
"failed": true, 
"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", 
"stdout": ""
```

}

When I replace `with_fileglob` with `with_items` in the task above, it throws a `msg": "Unable to find '../templates/apache/conf/*.conf' in expected paths."` error which is odd because the path does exist.

However when I hard code the configuration files like I did below, the task works as intended.  Writing the task this way defeats the purpose of looping since I have multiple configuration files to deploy

```
- name: Deploy apache configuration files
  template: src={{ item.src }} dest=/etc/httpd/{{ item.dest }} mode=0644
  with_items:
  - { src: "../templates/apache_templates/conf/vhost1.conf", dest: 'conf' }
  - { src: "../templates/apache_templates/conf.d/example1.conf", dest: 'conf.d' }
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: What is the question? Because everything works as expected. You misuse `with_fileglob` lookup and Ansible returns an error. Write two tasks and you're done.

Comment: 1) Never, ever include the answer as copy in your question. 2) Use a spell-checker. 3) Remove anything that doesn't help describe your problem more clearly (we know you have a problem without a solution, you would not be here if not). 4) Always, **always** include a question in your post. (i.e. a sentence ending in a question mark. I added one but it could be made more specific.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you question you are using two destination paths which can be extracted from your source path. So for above question you can use this. The config which you are using will not work. You can use it this way.

> **1.** `{{item | dirname | regex_replace('.*/','')}}` this will return  folder name, from the path. For example your path is `../templates/apache_templates/conf/*.conf` then `dirname` filter will return `../templates/apache_templates/conf` and `regex_replace`'s regex replace all till `/`, then result will be `conf`

```
---
- hosts: your_host
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: "Copy files from source to destination"
    copy:
     src: "{{item}}"
     dest: "{{item | dirname | regex_replace('.*/','')}}"
    with_fileglob:
    - "../templates/apache_templates/conf/*.conf"
    - "../templates/apache_templates/conf.d/*.conf"
---
```

Comment: Thank you @Sahil. I amended my question to reflect what actually worked based of your recommendation. I changed copy to template since the templates included variables and also added the `/etc/httpd` to the beginning of destination since it was complaining about not finding `conf` on the destination path.